# Using a jsp fmt tag in another tag

Tags: java, jsp

I'd like to be able to include the return value of a fmt tag in another tag:

```
<local:roundedBox boxTitle="<fmt:message key="somekey"/>">
content
</roundedBox>
```

I've run into this problem multiple times and it just seems like a stupid limitation of jsp.  Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an intermediate variable to store the result like this (code not tested)

```
<fmt:message key="somekey" var="formattedvarname" />
<local:roundedBox boxTitle="${formattedvarname}">
content
</roundedBox>
```

Comment: Ah!  I didn't know you could do that with a fmt tag.  Thanks :-)

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it so - that way the system will know it's answered and not just you. (And I get some points I guess, which is also supposed to be nice ;-)